# How can I make my Table right hand border shorter than the cell height with CSS?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

In the site http://www.domestika.org/foros the right hand side borders of the table are shorter than the cell height of each cell in each row. Tried to use inspect element, but just can't figure it out. Is a Div inside a Div?

Comment: It's magic.      (It's a div in a td and you need to work you your element inspector skills)

Comment: it is actually a left border not right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its using a div inside a td with padding.

You can use Firebug on Firefox, Webdeveloper tools in IE or Chrome (F12) to see it.

Would be something like this:

**CSS:**

```
.pad{
    padding: 10px;
}
.border {
    border-left: solid 1px #999;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<td class="pad">
    <div>content here</div>
</td>
<td class="pad">
    <div class="border">content here</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Tried still no cigar. An example maybe - how do I put in another DIV inside a td? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using a DIV inside a DIV (or in a TD) is the correct way to do this. Position and size the inner DIV according for the visual effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```css
.tdone {
  width: 130px;
  border-bottom: 0.1em dashed #CDCDCD;
  text-align: center;
}

.tdtwo {
  width: 130px;
  border-right: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 0.1em dashed #CDCDCD;
  text-align: center;
}

.cellpadding {
  padding: 20px;
  border-right: 0.1em solid #CDCDCD;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="15" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td class="tdone">
      <div class="cellpadding">
        registry.type
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="tdone">
      <div class="cellpadding">
        registry.quantity
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="tdone">
      <div class="cellpadding">
        registry.color
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="tdtwo">
      registry.brand
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```